# Bash autocomplete for IBM Cloud CLI?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, ibm-cloud, command-line-interface, zsh

I am using the [CLI for IBM Cloud](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/index.html#overview) in my bash environment. Is there support for autocomplete, i.e., automatic completion of commands and their options?

I am especially interested in the commands for the Kubernetes service and the container registry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autocompletion is supported, but not that well-advertised. The instructions can be found in the [IBM Cloud developer tools documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/enable_cli_autocompletion.html#enabling-shell-autocompletion-for-ibm-cloud-cli-linux-macos-only-). The following source needs to be added to the bash / zsh resource file or profile:

bash: `source /usr/local/ibmcloud/autocomplete/bash_autocomplete`
zsh: `source /usr/local/ibmcloud/autocomplete/zsh_autocomplete`

Comment: Which version of CLI are you using? Apparently it is not working on my machine. Any additional setup required?

Comment: It's the same. What about your environment? What version, what OS, what shell?

Comment: It's high sierra and zsh.

Comment: Please ask a separate question on how to enable it and provide the technical details and steps you completed. That's better than discussing it here.